# What is the syntax for writing comments in build.gradle file?

Tags: android, gradle, comments, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Looking down this `build.gradle` file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "package.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
}
```

What if I would like to write a comment on *why did I chose this library for this project*,

what is the syntax for writing comments in `build.gradle` file?

Comment: For Kotlin scripts (*.kts* files), it is the same as the regular Kotlin files: `//` for single-line comment and `/* */` for multi-line comments and `/** */` for KDoc comments.

Answer (score 345, accepted):

Easy:

```
// Single line comment

/*
 Multi
 line
 comment
*/
```

Answer (score 32):

Use the `//` or `/*  */`

For example:

```
        // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

/**
 * Returns the credential username used by Namirial Maven repository
 * Set this value in your ~/.gradle/gradle.properties with CREDENTIALS_USERNAME key
 * @return
 */
def getCredentialsMavenUsername() {
    return hasProperty('CREDENTIALS_USERNAME') ? CREDENTIALS_USERNAME : ""
}
```

Comment: Well that was quite odd, my Android Studio was not recognizing comment lines until I restarted it. Funny thing though it does not have any answers on the web.