# How to escape hash in markdown syntax?

Tags: escaping, markdown

How do I escape the hash value inside a code snippet in markdown?
All tries resulted to a red display of the character (invalid)

````
```gradle
# My gradle comment
artifactory_user=YOUR_ARTIFACTORY_USER
artifactory_password=YOUR_ARTIFACTORY_PW
```
````

I tried already

```
\\#
\#
##
&#35;
```

None of these works?!

Comment: What flavour of Markdown? HTML entities (&#35;) should definitely work in most parsers...

Comment: This doesn't work inside a code widget. Its gitlab flavored markdown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because it *is* invalid. [Gradle syntax is based on Groovy syntax](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html#sec:the_gradle_build_language). Single-line comments in both [Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32569925/354577) and [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_single_line_comment) use `//`, not `#`:

````
```gradle
// My gradle comment
```
````

Thanks for the OP for pointing out that `gradle.properties` files use `#` for comments. The following code block with the language set to `properties` works as expected:

````
```properties
# My gradle comment
artifactory_user=YOUR_ARTIFACTORY_USER
artifactory_password=YOUR_ARTIFACTORY_PW
```
````

Comment: You are fully right, I got messed up since it was the gradle.properties. So the right syntax is "properties"... and then it works without any escaping character.